# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined even after API fetched correctly in console in Async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Hi I am trying to create a API based news search webapp using JS. So here's the function where I am getting the error

```
async function fetchUsers(searchTerm, searchLimit, sortBy){
//RETURNS PROMISES
let url=`some api parameters searchTerm, SearchLimit and sorby is passed`;

const res=await fetch(url);
const data=await res.json();
const article = [];


document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=`
${data.article.map(function(post){
  //NEWSCARD
  return(`
  <ul id="news-article" style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li class="article">
      <div class="card mb-2">
        <img class="article-image" class="card-img-top" src="${post.urlToimage}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="article-title" class="card-title">${post.title}</h2>
          <p class="article-description" class="card-text">${truncateString(post.selftext, 100)}</p>
          <a class="article-link" href="${post.url}" target="_blank
          " class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          <hr>
          <span class="article-author" class="badge badge-secondary">Subreddit: ${post.subreddit}</span> 
          <span class="badge badge-dark">Score: ${post.score}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  `)
}
 .join('') 
  )}} fetchUsers();
```

The main error is observed at ${data.article.map(function(post){

Could anyone suggest what could be the possible reason for it ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe check if `data` is not empty ?

Comment: what is `res.json()` returning?  is there a `.article` in there?  Is it empty?

Comment: Show your api response please.

Comment: I tried to check the data with console.log and it returns the data of the API correctly in the console.

Comment: Try debugging your code a bit. I recommend adding `debugger;` or `console.log(data)` after `const data=...` and see what is inside the data variable. Then please show us example of how data looks

Comment: Anyway your article is empty that's why it's undefined.Nothing can be mapped.

Comment: add `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` after your `data` assignment to see what you really have.  Clearly `data.article` is undefined

Comment: Why not just data.map directly?

Comment: The response has an `undefined` `article` property, are you sure the request is correct?

Comment: Could you insert the response into the question?

Comment: Attaching the screenshot of console.log(data). Also tried to add console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment:  You have a typo. Instead of "data.article.map" you need to type "data.article**s**.map".

Comment: my goodness don't tell me that misir's comment is where its at...

Comment: This is why posting the response is helpful, lol.

Comment: I tried to rename it to articles as mentioned by Misir but it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to narrow down and find the issue is to first write the code in clean way.

I would suggest breakdown your code in manageable parts and try debug features in browser with **debugger** or **console.log()** works really well.

There are even better options like [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) where you can write your code and test it with the help of code to get more confidence with tools like [jest](https://jestjs.io/)

```
NOTE: pseudo code
function getPosts() { 
   return posts
}

function renderPost(post) { 
   return `<div>${post}</div> ` 
}

function render() {
   const posts = getPosts()
   console.info('post -> ', posts)
   const postsMarkup = posts.map((post) => renderPost(post)).join('');
   console.info('postsMarkup -> ', postsMarkup)
   document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = postMarkup
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the document.getElementByid section is being called asynchronously, perhaps at a time when the data has not returned anything, or when the article variable is not even declared, you can try this:

```
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();

    populateList(data);
}

function populateList(article) {
    const innerHTML = article.map(post => `
    <ul id="news-article" style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li class="article">
            <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="article-image" class="card-img-top" src="${post.urlToimage}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="article-title" class="card-title">${post.title}</h2>
                    <p class="article-description" class="card-text">${truncateString(post.selftext, 100)}</p>
                    <a class="article-link" href="${post.url}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                    <hr>
                    <span class="article-author" class="badge badge-secondary">Subreddit: ${post.subreddit}</span> 
                    <span class="badge badge-dark">Score: ${post.score}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    `);

    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: how can a section of code inside his function be called asynchronously?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Definitely the way to go when trying to do a fetch with async (as opposed to `.then`) statements.  On first read it seemed to me that the author's `.map` statement was firing before the api call was made and data was defined, as the `.map` clause did not have an `await` in front of it.

Comment: I tried the above code but nothing is returned in the output screen once the search button is hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without the `async` and `await` keywords, and just use a callback within a `.then` statement, like this:

```
function fetchUsers(searchTerm, searchLimit, sortBy){

  let url=`some url based on params`;

  fetch(url)
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( data => populateList(data) )

}

function populateList(data) {
    const innerHTML = data.articles.map(post => `
    <ul id="news-article" style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li class="article">
            <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="article-image" class="card-img-top" src="${post.urlToimage}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="article-title" class="card-title">${post.title}</h2>
                    <p class="article-description" class="card-text">${truncateString(post.selftext, 100)}</p>
                    <a class="article-link" href="${post.url}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                    <hr>
                    <span class="article-author" class="badge badge-secondary">Subreddit: ${post.subreddit}</span> 
                    <span class="badge badge-dark">Score: ${post.score}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    `);

    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = innerHTML;
}

fetchUsers(searchTerm, searchLimit, sortBy);
```

Also, hijacking Misir Jafarov's comment, the array in your `data` object is called `articles`, but you're trying to map from `article`.  I feel like you'd still have problems without this typo, but that will definitely hang you up.  Thanks @Misir Jafarov

Comment: The above code returns 400 Bad request to the API URL and article.map is not a function error

Comment: Did you actually bother to put in the proper URL template string or did you just copy and paste my code...?

Comment: Hey seth, ofcouse I did put the proper URL.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting the 400 Bad request error then...

Answer (score 0):

The issue (from observing the error in the console) is that your code is attempting to access a property that doesn't exist.

Without access to the exact data that you're using, it'd be impossible to inform you of what the exact problem is. However, here are some steps I'd take to diagnose the issue:

1. Set up a breakpoint (`debugger`) or a `console.log(data)` right after `data` is assigned so that you can observe it.
2. Either click through the `data` variable in your browser's dev tools, or check the assumptions your code is making programmatically.

In terms of programmatically checking your code's assumptions:

1. Verify that `data` is an object by running `typeof data` should return `object`
2. Verify that `data` does in fact have a property `article` by running `Object(data).hasOwnProperty('article')`
3. Verify that `data.article` is an array by running `Array.isArray(data.article)`
4. Verify that each `article` within `data` has a `selfText`, `subreddit`, `score` (using step 2)

My guess is you'll find a misalignment between your code and the data in this process. If not, I'd like to know where you land.